# How to do clipping in 3D?

Tags: clipping

I have a list of vertices, I want to clip these inside the view frustum.

Here's what I am planning to do :

- First I will loop through my list and check vertex $v$ for $|v.x| \le |v.w|$, $|v.y| \le |v.w|$ and $|v.z| \le |v.w|$.

  - If it fails then I will remove it from the list and add it to a `failedVertex` list.
  - If it passes the test, then I will set up a inner loop to iterate through `failedVertex` list. For each vertex in `failedVertex`, I will find the intersection of the line between my "passed" vertex and current failed vertex with the view frustum. I will then add the intersection point to my `out` list.

    - Eg: if $v$ is a passed vertex and $w^i$ is `failedVertex[i]`, then I need the intersection between $r = v + \lambda(v - w^i)$ and my view frustum.
  - At the end of the inner loop I will add the passed vertex to my `out` list.

I have one problem with this approach, how do I find the intersection between my line and the view frustum ? I don't know the equations of the six planes of my view frustum, I don't really want to calculate the equation of the 6 planes.

I am not using OpenGL or Direct3D ...

Comment: OpenGL (and presumably DX) does clipping in "clip-space", that is vertices after perspective projection so the view frustum becomes a unit cube were clipping edges is simpler.